# Query-by-example skip primitives?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

Spring supports creating queries by examples of the object to look for. Like:

```
//if not setting the age, it will always look for age=0
Person p = new Person();
p.setLastName("Smith");
List<Person> foundPersons = personRepository.findAll(Example.of(p));

@Entity
public class Person {
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;
  private LocalDate dob;
  private int age;
}
```

Problem: if the `@Entity` has primitive fields, then their default value will actually be used for creating the query. The example above will result in:

`SELECT * from persons where lastname := 'Smith' and age := 0`

In my example I have a database field where `age` must always be filled, thus is not allowed to be `null`. Therefore the entity has a primitive `int age` field.

Of course I could now change the field to `Integer age`, but then I'd marking the field being an optional nullable attribute, which is not true.

So, how can I skip primitives that have not been set on the `Example`?

[Reference Example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/jpa/query-by-example)

Comment: I would use the Integer approach. If you have constraints on age, i think there won't be any problems

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can do it:

```
Person p = new Person();
p.setLastName("Smith");

Example criteria = Example.create(p).setPropertySelector(
    Example.NotNullOrZeroPropertySelector.INSTANCE
);
List<Person> foundPersons = session.createCriteria(Person.class).add(criteria).list();
```

`Example.NotNullOrZeroPropertySelector.INSTANCE` is a property selector that includes only properties that are not `null` and non-zero (if numeric)

UPD

Above an example for Hibernate `org.hibernate.criterion.Example` class. For `org.springframework.data.domain.Example` you can ignore primitive fields by manually specifying names of these fields:

```
Person p = new Person();
p.setLastName("Smith");

ExampleMatcher matcher = ExampleMatcher.matching().withIgnorePaths("age").withIgnoreNullValues();

Example criteria = Example.of(p, matcher);
List<Person> foundPersons = personRepository.findAll(criteria);
```

Comment: What about primitives like `short, byte, boolean`?

Comment: `Short` and `Byte` are also numeric types, so they will be ignored. Anyway, you can write your own implementation of `PropertySelector` for boolean and numeric types

Comment: @membersound I'm really sorry because I confused 2 classes, so I updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

I use reactive java and spring data.
Here is repository:

```
public interface MyObjectRepository extends ReactiveCrudRepository<MyObject, Long>, ReactiveQueryByExampleExecutor<MyObject> {}
```

Service:

```
public Mono<Page<MyObject>> getAllBySupport(Pageable pageable, Boolean isSupported) {
   ExampleMatcher m;
   Example<MyObject> ex;

   if (isSupported != null) {
      m = ExampleMatcher.matching().withIgnoreNullValues();
      ex = Example.of(MyObject.builder().isSupport(isSupported).build(), m);
   } else {
      //isSupport field in Myobject has boolean primitive type
      //if parameter isSupported is null - I ignore this parameter in example
      //and result has objects with true and false isSupport field
      m = ExampleMatcher.matching().withIgnorePaths("isSupport").withIgnoreNullValues();
      ex = Example.of(new MyObject(), m);
   }

    return myObjectRepository.findBy(ex, (p) -> p.page(pageable))
            .map(s -> new PageImpl<>(s.stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()), pageable, s.getTotalElements()));
```

With this code you also can hava pagination and sorting

Wish you luck:)

Answer (score 0):

In Spring boot, i was getting primitives as 0. so i have solved as below

```
     ExampleMatcher matcher = ExampleMatcher.matching().withIgnorePaths("parentId");//ignore primitives
     Example<ConfigMetadata> configExample = Example.of(config, matcher);
     if(config.getParentId()!=null && config.getParentId() != 0) { //if primitives other than null/zero, create new example which includes them
        configExample.getProbe().setParentId(config.getParentId());
        configExample = Example.of(configExample.getProbe());
     }
```